# pandas dataframe multiplication with missing values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, error-handling

I have a dataframe with 2columns (floating types), but one of them has missing data represented by a string ".." 
When performing a multiplication operation, an exception is raised and the whole operation is aborted.
What I try to achieve is to perform the multiplication for the float values and leave ".." for the missing ones.

```
2 *  6  
.. * 4
```

should give `[12, ..]`
I found a naive solution consisting in replacing `..` by 0 then perform the multiplication, then replace back the 0 by `..` 
It doesn't seem very optimized. Any other solution?

```
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)  
mg['x'] = df['x'] * df["Value"]  
 for col in mg.columns:
    mg[col] = mg[col].apply(update)
def update(v):
    if (v == 0):
        return ".."
    return v
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [Series.isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
import numpy as np
mg['x'] = np.where(df['X'].isna(), df['X'], df['X']*df['Value'])
```

If you want to replace the null with '..' and multiply others:

```
mg['x'] = np.where(df['X'].isna(), '..', df['X']*df['Value'])
```

So anywhere the Value of column x is null, the it remains the same, otherwise it's multiplies with the value of the corresponding row of Value column

In you solution you can also do a fillna(1):

```
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'], errors='coerce').fillna(1)  
mg['x'] = df['x'] * df["Value"]
```

This is how I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [ 2, np.nan],
                  'Value': [6, 4]})
df

     X  Value
0   2.0  6
1   NaN  4

np.where(df['X'].isna(), df['X'], df['X']*df['Value'])
array([12., nan])
```